# Symfony 4 The service "api_platform.swagger.action.ui" has a dependency on a non-existent service "twig"

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

When installing api-platform with composer

```
composer.phar require "api-platform/core"
```

I endup with the error

```
The service "api_platform.swagger.action.ui" has a dependency on a non-existent service "twig".
```

```
Anyone knows if api-platform is compatible with Symfony 4?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 4 is provided without the twig dependency.
You have to add it: `composer req twig`

Comment: I do have twig, ```composer.phar require "twig/twig"``` do I have to enable it as a service, anyone knows how to do that in symfony4, docs do not say anything

Answer (score 1):

MatMouth, you are right. to install twig in Symfony4 you need command
    composer require twig
and not:
composer require "twig/twig"

Thanks for your help